# IdentityServer4 .net core, is it possible to protect controllers on the same IdentityServer with a token generated from the same server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, jwt

Normally when we use IdentityServer4 we would use this setup:
[image]

Where we would have an

- Authorization Server (Identity Server)
- A Client (which will request a token)
- A Web Api (Protected with authorize)

Say we have this setup, but I need to add Protected Api's on the Authorization Server (identity server), by protected I mean with the authorize attribute. Is this possible? cause I haven't found any samples online, and I have been trying to implement it by adding the JwtBearer code on the IdentityServer (JwtBearer is normally added on the WebApi project that you want protected, with Authority set as your IdentityServer domain).

In short what i'm trying to achieve is have the Protected Resource on the same Authorization Server. Is this possible?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to do that exactly? What kind of functionality on an authentication server needs to be protected? Seems a little ironic don't you think? Maybe this functionality would be better encapsulated by a separate API which accepts tokens from the identity server. It would help if you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve and why

Comment: so your answer is that I should not do that (agreed). But is it possible or not?

Comment: i need it for role and organizational management

Comment: That's pretty vague and doesn't, by itself, justify putting it into the identity server. Organisational roles seem to me to be something separate from authentication and authorisation. (Of course, authorisation claims might flow from someone's organisational role, but actually managing the data which describes their role isn't the function of the authentication server. As I suspected, other than exceptional circumstances this functionality should almost certainly just be in a separate application in the normal way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with some additional configuration. There is an argument against doing this, but I've had use cases where it was necessary.

For local API authentication you need the following additional configuration in Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ....
  // After services.AddIdentityServer()
  services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();
}
```

For reference see the [docs](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html).

You also need to configure the local resource:

```
  public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis =>
    new ApiResource[]
    {
      // your other resources....
      new ApiResource(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName)
    };
```

For the client you need to add the local API scope:

```
  AllowedScopes =
  {
    // your other scopes....
    IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName
  }
```

And then you need to specify the local API policy as part of the `Authorize` attribute on your API:

```
[Authorize(LocalApi.PolicyName)]
```

See a local API [example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/host/LocalApiController.cs#L13).

Answer (score 1):

You can put IdentityServer and the protected resource on the same machine, but I would advice against it.

My experience is that it gets really hard to know who is doing what and it will be much hard to fully understand and reason about what is going on. I always recommend putting IdentityServer, the client and the API in independent services. Just to get a clean separation of concerns.

Comment: i agree with you, but we needed it for a special case as i mentioned above. anyway. localapi did the trick for me.